# Why is Xcode 4 not running my latest build?

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

I was originally working from my desktop on a project. I then decide to continue working on the same project over at a friend's house. I come home and decide to use the newest project (on a different folder even) open the project I run it and it shows the same thing I had before... for some reason it appears nothing got updated.

Any ideas why this is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try cleaning the project (Command-Shift-K) to see if that helps. I usually have to do this when I don't change code and only change a resource such as a xib or image file.